# Exact definition of ceramics

Tags: materials, ceramics

Exactly what are "ceramics"? I found a lot of similar "definitions" of that term online, e.g. on Wikipedia and [here](https://www.sciencelearn.org.nz/resources/1769-what-are-ceramics).

These (and other) sources essentially state that ceramics are non-metallic, non-organic materials. And they state the most prominent examples.

But these only seem to be necessary properties. **Are there sufficient criteria based on which one can definitely decide whether a certain material is ceramic? Is this list of criteria comprehensive?**

Is there even a widely accepted clear definition at all?

Comment: Concrete isn't metallic or organic, but I wouldn't call it ceramic (So, I'd say that list of criteria *isn't* comprehensive, although I don't have a better definition to offer without research)

Comment: @JonathanRSwift thank's for this nice counter-example

Comment: I think you're supposed to Just Know -- although the concrete example cited by @JonathanRSwift suggests that there needs to be a kiln involved someplace (and not before you mix powder with water).

Comment: A fairly general definition would be "an inorganic compound of a metal and a non-metal". You have to stretch your definitions of "metal" and "inorganic" a bit to include compounds like silicon carbide, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic (materials science) definition of a ceramic is a compound that is held together by a network of *covalent bonds*. The fact that these bonds are directional means it is *non-metallic*- deformation by dislocation-mediated slip does not occur (so no ductility mechanisms are active at ambient temperature) and the substance is a poor conductor of both heat and electricity (since the electrons responsible for holding the material together are immobile).

Comment: This sounds good. Do you maybe have any source for this, so that I take a closer look?

Comment: Either of the two materials science texts by Van Vlack (probably out of print) or the excellent text by Shackelford (more recent).